# C# WPF positioning progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and XAML. 
I would like to move a progress bar element to a specific area but it doesn't move. I was googling for the last hour and didn't find any solutions.

[image: Picture of GUI]

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="ArduinoSMS_sender.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ArduinoSMS_sender"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="SendMEEE" Height="506" Width="750" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="menu_open_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Save" Click="menu_save_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Import" Click="menu_import_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Export" Click="menu_export_Click"/>


            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel Height="457" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ProgressBar Height="10" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>


    <ListView x:Name="osebe_listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" Margin="30,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="osebe_listView_SelectionChanged" d:IsLocked="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Naziv podjetja" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nazivPodjetja}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ime}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Priimek" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding priimek}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding naslov}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Pošta" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding posta}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mobilna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding mobilnaSt}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Stacionarna številka" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stacionarnaSt}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="E-naslov" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding eMail}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Skupina" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding skupina}"/>


            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button x:Name="urediSkupine_btn" Content="Manage groups" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="248,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Click="urediSkupine_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="izbranaSkupina_cbx" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="izberiOsebeSkupine_btn" Content="Select people" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Click="izberiOsebeSkupine_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="dodajOsebo_btn" Content="Add contact" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="dodajOsebo_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="urediOsebo_btn" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="190,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="urediOsebo_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="zbrisiOsebo_btn" Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="zbrisiOsebo_btn_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="1.067,0.682" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="isci_tb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="30,423,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="search" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1" TextChanged="isci_tb_TextChanged" d:IsLocked="True"  >
        <TextBox.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </TextBox.Background>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="izbraniKontakti_tb" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="187,423,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Selected: " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1" d:IsLocked="True"  >
        <TextBox.Background>
            <ImageBrush/>
        </TextBox.Background>
    </TextBox>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="smsText_rtb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" Margin="423,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309" d:IsLocked="True">
        <FlowDocument/>
    </RichTextBox>
    <Button x:Name="shraniSporocilo_btn" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="shraniSporocilo_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="odpriSporocilo_btn" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="585,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="odpriSporocilo_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="poslji_btn" Content="Send" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="540,423,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Height="37" Click="poslji_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="izberiVse_btn" Content="S" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="282,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" RenderTransformOrigin="5.87,0.364" Height="22" Click="izberiVse_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="odstraniIzbor_btn" Content="D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" RenderTransformOrigin="5.87,0.364" Click="odstraniIzbor_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
    <Label x:Name="status_lbl" Content="Status: nepovezan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,446,0,-2" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>

</Grid>
```

Need help, please.

Comment: Show your XAML code and I will help you :)

Comment: Googling "WPF layout tutorial" should give you plenty of sites quickly - this is a reasonable overview of some ways to position controls http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

Comment: Thanks :)  This XAML is really giving me a headache

Comment: You placed the `ProgressBar` in the `DockPanel` right below your menu. No wonder it appears up there. If it should be next to the Send button, then put it next to the Send button ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the way the Send button is positioned using the HorizontalAlignment & VerticalAlignment & Margin properties.

The StackPanel is not required & the ProgressBar should be moved from the DockPanel to the main Grid.

Something like this should place it close to your send Button

```
....
....
<Button x:Name="odstraniIzbor_btn" Content="D" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="22" RenderTransformOrigin="5.87,0.364" Click="odstraniIzbor_btn_Click" d:IsLocked="True"/>
<Label x:Name="status_lbl" Content="Status: nepovezan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,446,0,-2" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsLocked="True"/>

<ProgressBar Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="423,423,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a special reason why you can't drag and drop some elements? This and panels I couldn't move around with mouse, which is rather confusing.

Comment: As a note - I know layout is a personal (or possibly corporate) thing - but I prefer to have the XAML layout reflect the displayed image. So I would group controls that are displayed close to each other close to each other in the XAML & in the same top to bottom order - rather than group controls by type. It is easier to find the controls that way.

Comment: I think it may have been the the StackPanel causing the problem - by selecting the ProgressBar to drag it - it will be being dragged within the StackPanel, as the StackPanel auto-arranges the controls then nothing would be achieved. If you selected & dragged the StackPanel, then you may have got the correct positioning, but a single control in a StackPanel is a bit pointless.

Comment: Allright!  I did not change the XAML code since I used the toolbox to drag items in the wpf. I'll keep your note in mind, thank you

Comment: I deleted the default StackPanel, that is covering the entire interface. Now I found out that the menu is covering the whole page for some reason. Can I simply narrow it down to size and put it at the top? And do I need a stack panel or can I create many for each section one to put in my elements?

Comment: Yes you should be able to adjust the size and position of your menu by using the same properties in the DockPanel + Height & Width. A StackPanel is used to automatically position multiple controls inside of it without overlap - they can be optionally placed horizontally or vertically & can automatically move if controls are hidden (by collapsing). StackPanels can be nested to vary the orientation. It may be worthwhile creating a WPF application to playing with the various options to see what way of positioning elements works best for you - there can be many ways of getting the same effect.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was thinking about making a dummy project for playing with layouts. Will do that today.